# Intercept $http request and return response without server request

Tags: angularjs, http

I want to, on certain http requests, return data from memory rather than letting it hit the server.  I know I can write http interceptors but I'm not sure how to actually return the response from the request?

```
myModule.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        // optional method
        'request': function (config) {
            // return my data here [200], and stop the call from going through
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What we did at work, is we wrapped  http request in a cacheService who always return a promise . In summary : `return isCachedObject ? $q.resolve(cacheInstance) : return resultat from httpRequest`.  Can it be an option for you?

Comment: @ÉricRoberge Yeah that woudl work but was hoping for a more elegant solution :) Maybe there isn't one!

Comment: Another option is to cache the promise of the httpRequest. So next calls to the the same request can be bind to the promise of the first call.

Comment: I believe Éric's solution is the most elegant you'll get. You could cancel the request in the intercepter, and when the request is rejected, you could use the requestError interceptor to return your cached data instead of an error. That'll do the job without using a wrapper, but it is less elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that only uses interceptors. I'd still argue Érics solution in the comments is more elegant, but now you have different options to consider.

```
app.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, myCache) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            var cached = myCache.getCachedData(config.params);
            if(cached){
                return $q.reject({cachedData: cached, config: config });
            }
            return config;
        },

        response: function(response){
            // myCache.saveData(response.data);
        },

        responseError: function(rejection) {      
            if(rejection.cachedData){
                return $q.resolve(rejection.cachedData);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: $q.resolve not found in my case rather it worked with $q.when(rejection.cachedData)... I'm using angularJs 1.2.20....great help nevertheless...thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check this article: [Caching HTTP](http://volgarev.me/blog/127610878442)

Or you can use cache parameters for `$http` (check more in angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

```
$http.get('api/path',{
    cache: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use the cache in this way.  For large data it causes bottle necks.

Comment: So then, check first link.